# CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]

Tags: yii

Делаю блог на Yii framework все по официальной инструкции. Вот только когда дело касается непосредственного добавления в MySQL, будь то пост или комментарий возникает ошибка CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Скрин полной ошибки:
https://gyazo.com/546d271ec076abe99f0e0c8657edf75c

Проблема в том что в инструкции об этом ничего не сказано. Помогите пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка происходит во внешнем ключе. Ваша таблица с комментариями имеет каскадную связь с `post`, вы не передаете `post_id` в `comment` и соответственно получаете ошибку. Проще говоря по схеме вашей СУБД комментарии обязательно должны быть привязаны к постам.

Если комментарий может быть не привязан к посту, то сделаете значение по умолчанию `NULL` в поле `post_id`